# How to merge two or more smooch user/conversation via API

Tags: smooch

If a user messages via Smooch through Facebook messenger as well as email. Two separate smooch user is created. Is there a way via the Smooch API to merge these two users into a single user so the profile information as well as the conversation is merged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no API to merge two `appUser`.

Comment: Are there any plans to add such capabilities to Smooch or is that left to the business systems by design?

Comment: We do plan on adding it soon. You can watch our changelog https://docs.smooch.io/changelog/ or follow our api spec repo to be notified once it will be available https://github.com/smooch/api-spec